# CMS - how to make it easy to set up?

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, content-management-system, goal-tracking

I have been wondering a thing in a day or two. I was wondering that if I am e.g. Adding a comment with some jQuery on a submit button would it then be stupid to make a file - for example:

tracking.php?Param=[...]

And then Everything that can be made to a goal in analytics will have it's own parameter. The file does not have to include any code - the visit of the file should be enough for analytics, right?

So if I in my system has two formulars and want to have set up some goals on each of them and use tracking.php as my "goal-URL" is this an okay way to do so:

Calling the file in jQuery as this:
tracking.php?Param=form1
tracking.php?Param=form2

As mentioned above the file would not have any content - just an empty file. And therefore it shouldn't make any delay - is that right?

OR is this just a bad workaound, that I have come up with in some late hours of thinking?

Comment: What is the purpose of 'making a file'? Why try to reinvent how GA works, instead of using their API?

Comment: Well - for sure I don't know everything about GA. What do you mean?? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, that's not going to work.  GA code needs to be executed at some point in time. GA does not automatically track requests made by javascript (jquery).

And on that note, as Mads Jenson mentioned, you are reinventing the wheel.  Unfortunately for some weird reason, you cannot use custom variables or events as goals, only URLs...I hear rumors that GA is going to eventually add that in, but until then, you are stuck with popping virtual page views to make goals.

So, on a given page, if you want to track something as a goal, just call the following:

```
var virtualPage = "/tracking/[...]";
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview',virtualPage]);
```

you would put whatever value you want in virtualPage but "/tracking/" as a prefix, followed by a specific value is a clean way to do it, and is similar to your idea of having a single url w/ unique parameter values (though you can pass it exactly as you put it if you want...).

You can put that in a wrapper function to be called on an onclick, hover, after a certain amount of time has passed, if some other condition is met... whatever you want.

But fair warning, there is a [limit to how many requests GA will allow to make to it in per visit](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html#implementationConsiderations), so don't go crazy with tracking everything under the sun as a goal, or you may end up screwing yourself on tracking other custom tracking you've done, or even basic page view hits...

Comment: With that said I have one little question: So that means if I only want to track if $_POST isset I can just do that on a given page and then I can e.g. track only when comments are put into the database?
And further - isn't it correct that I can also track goals on the URL (without inserting extra code) ? eg make a goal-conversion everytime someone visits domain.com/this-page ??

Comment: re: $_POST:  Okay, if you wanna track if $_POST isset, because that is server-side, you are going to have to either make a request to the GA url server-side, appending relevant info in the url (using cURL)...or pop the code on the next page the user goes to after the post, if it isset.

Comment: re: tracking goals on the URL (without inserting extra code) : yes, you can base goals on the actual URLs of the pages a user goes to in general, without additional code - that is because you would have the global code on the page which is calling that same _trackPageview already.

Comment: And on that note...there is one last thing I want to warn you about, as far as calling _trackPageview at random times for goal tracking: This is effectively sending a page view to GA, so it will affect your reports like pageview reports. What this means is that to just get general traffic information, you will have to make filters to filter out those urls-as-goals.  That is why it is important to make the virtual page value something unique only to the goal tracking, like "/tracking/..." and make sure there are no other pages on your site with that value

Comment: re: $_POST: I suppose *technically* you could onsubmit..assuming your form is method post...trigger a function to check if there are values in any of your form fields, and if so, trigger the GA code and then follow through with the .submit().  But that doesn't really mean the comment made it to your db..it could for instance fail your server-side form validation (assuming you have that...you do have that right? seeing as how you are taking user input and putting it into a db...)

Comment: Yeah of course I have serverside validation :-) But well - I am actually thinking that it is quite hard to set up - what this means is that if I insert the virtualPage on a page the visit (if the VirtualPage is triggered) is being saved in the analytics two times?

Comment: well, yes...but for submitted comments specifically, you can make the goal the URL the user lands on after they comment is successfully submitted - count THAT as the goal and only trigger the code once.